# IoT wireless solenoid circuit

Tags: design, timer, watchdog, nrf24l01, attiny85

I am a Newbie and I do not have a lot of expirience. The circuit has been put together from pieces I have found on the internet. My goal is to develop a reliable wireless solenoid circuit to water my tomato plants on my balkony.

The circuit I have developed so far. 
https://easyeda.com/editor#id=b929cf452b52475bb0b40aca272a42e8.

In order to make the circuit failsafe, I came up with the following idea:

- Circuit turns on, valve is closed, watchdog is disabled
- ATTiny85 receives periodic PING from Master station
- First PING will enable watchdog
- ATTiny85 sends periodic heartbeat to watchdog for each subsequent received PING
- Missing heartbeat/PING will reset the microsontroller and close the valve

I would really appreciate if someone from the community could look over the design and let me know how to improve the circuit and if above approach is OK to avoid a permanent open valve.

Comment: It looks like your 555 timer, your choice of C8 and R9 is dependent on what you want your duty cycle to be for the chip... so that needs to be a decision you need to make. I did not see an R6 but I'm assuming you mean R5 instead. For R5, you should review the electrical specifications and see if you can find anything about the RESET.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After reading the datasheets again I have realised a big design mistake and I had to remove the timer circuit and to replace the watchdog.